# Is the Skywalker last name exclusive?

Tags: star-wars

Are there any characters in the SW universe that carry the last name Skywalker, and who *aren't* related to Anakin/Luke/Leia/etc.?

I.e., is the Skywalker name completely exclusive to the Vader lineage, or, are there others?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Skywalker_family), all known Skywalkers are descended from Shmi (at least genetically; there have also been multiple Skywalker clones in various media).

> The Skywalker family was a Force-sensitive Human bloodline whose first known member was Shmi Skywalker.

This is not a directly canonical answer; however, the wiki is generally quite well maintained, and I doubt that an unrelated Skywalker would make it through without it being mentioned on the family's page.

Comment: That family tree doesn't look all that complete to me. Where is Ben Solo? He is undeniably an important character in episode VII and VIII.

Comment: @kasperd I think the family tree refers to the old canon (Expanded Universe) as created by many novels, games and other media. It got "replaced" by the new sequel trilogy canon. This is obvious from looking at Han Solo's descendants.

Comment: Yes, the fact that it's on the [Legends](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Legends) tab indicates that it was based on the Expanded Universe (i.e. most official Star Wars media besides the films and the Clone Wars animated series) that were retconned to be non-canon before Episode VII was released. That said, some of that info may appear in the Canon tab as well.